# Function get_partition(geometry, unknown) does not exist - Nominatim tiger data import

Tags: postgis, postgresql, tiger, nominatim

Ive install Nominatim with postgres9.3 and postgis 2.1, imported osm data ok and now trying to import tiger data (tiger2013 edges) for the house numbers.

The import looks to go ok, but there is no data, and the log for postgresql has:

---

UTC ERROR: function get_partition(geometry, unknown) does not exist at character 8

UTC HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

UTC QUERY: SELECT get_partition(place_centroid, 'us')

---

I looked at the source code and in functions.sql it has

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_partition(in_country_code VARCHAR(10)) RETURNS INTEGER.

EDIT
_
I asked this over on  https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/34315/issue-importing-tiger-data-into-nominatim and it turns out there was a bug in nominatim, I should have used the stable version rather than grabbing the latest copy from git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this over on https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/34315/issue-importing-tiger-data-into-nominatim and it turns out there was a bug in nominatim which is now fixed